# Survival curve in early humans

Tags: human-biology, natural-selection, population-dynamics, medicine, demography

The [survival curve/function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) describes the probability of a given individual to survive to age $x$. In humans, today's survival function is very much influenced by medicine. This leads me to wonder what the survival function looked like before modern medicine. Typically I wonder what the survival function looked like during the paleolithic age.

**What did the survival function looked like during the paleolithic age?**

**Why did the survival function looked like that? What were the major causes of mortality for males and for females?**

Comment: I posted an answer based on the same info as the answer [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26343/fecundity-per-woman-in-early-humans), since those papers can be useful for this question as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain a full survival curve (basically a full life table) you would need to make quite a number of assumptions, since the data for paleolithic societies is scattered and probably biased. This is however not a field I know well, but I can point you to one recent paper ([White, 2014)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ajpa.22495/full) that explores how the ratio of young and old individuals in a population relates to demographic rates, using agent-based models. Using such a model you can obtain smooth survival curves and also explore how different assumptions will affect the survival curves.

There are also data from recent or current hunter-gatherer societies that can be used to approximate what the survival curves looked like during the paleolithic. For instance,  [Hewlett (1991)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12317265) ([pdf here](http://anthro.vancouver.wsu.edu/media/PDF/demo_childcare.pdf)) has compiled survival rate data for individual hunter-gatherer societies (along with other demographic rates and data from other types of pre-industrial societies). The child mortality rate (deaths before age 15) often lie in the range 40-50% in active (mobile) and sedentary hunter-gatherer societies, with an infant mortality rate usually between 10-30% (death before 12 months of age). This indicates a fairly steep survival curve, which is the reason why the average age of paleolithic people is often estimated to ~25 years. This doesn't mean that most people died around the age of 25, just that the distribution of ages was very skewed and non-normal. Many died young, but people that survived to adulthood could become much older than 25.