# Infant Death Adjusted Historical Human Lifespan

Tags: life-history, lifespan

I had found a good paper at one point to describe this but I can't seem to locate something similar now. I am looking for a manuscript that describes average human lifespans throughout history/prehistory especially adjusted for infant and child deaths but it would be nice if there was un-adjusted data as well. Does anybody know of a reference with this information?

Comment: Related Q/A with some relevant references: [Survival curve in early humans](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26341/survival-curve-in-early-humans/26354#26354)

Comment: I assume you are asking about expected (mean/median) age of death, for people that survived young childhood(?).

Comment: @fileunderwater Unless I'm missing it I do not see the answer at the linked page, but yes I am looking for mean/median age of death for those that survived childhood compared across time (ideally prehistoric times up until recent times).

Comment: The link goes directly to the answer (Q above). This doesn't directly answer your question though, but contains some information on infant/child mortality in different types of human societies.